# Особове закінчення "м" замість "мо" дієслів першої особи множини

Tags: словотворення, дієвідмінювання

Як приклад явища, описаного в заголовку, наведу декілька рядків Державного Гімну України (джерело [Вікіпедія](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D1%96%D0%BC%D0%BD_%D0%A3%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D0%B8), текст (щонайпізніше 1990):

> Запану**єм** і ми, браття, у своїй сторонці.

> Душу й тіло ми полож**им** за нашу свободу,

> І покаж**ем**, що ми, браття, козацького роду.

> Стан**ем**, браття, в бій кривавий від Сяну до Дону

Зауважу, що в Гімні також використовується й стандартне особове закінчення:

> В ріднім краю панувати не да**мо** нікому

Шукаючи яку-небудь інформацію щодо такого особового закінчення, мені довелося знайти лише малу примітку [з нового правопису 2019](https://slovnyk.ua/pravopys.php?prav_par=115)

> особові форми допоміжного дієслова бути — буду, будеш, буде, будемо **(зрідка будем)**

Чи несе така форма якийсь сенс, відмінний від стандартної форми? Коли її можна вживати? Як вона опинилась в українській мові, інакше кажучи, яка її етимологія?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> <sub>*Запитник*</sub>
>
> Як вона опинилась в українській мові, інакше кажучи, яка її етимологія?

Це різна проява звука **ъ** [як](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AA#%D0%97%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%BA_%D1%8A) надкороткого **у** — [ŭ], котрий [зазвичай] або став як **о**, або зник. Зазвичай наводжу слово *сон*, котре [походить](//goroh.pp.ua/%D0%95%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%96%D1%8F/%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BD#17983) від *sъnъ*, де друге зникло, а перше стало як **о**, але [зазвичай] зникаїть при відмѣнках — [*без*] *сна*.

Декотрі мови і, шчо важливѣше нам, діалекти могли реалізувати [як](//webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:obWBtpO79AoJ:https://is.muni.cz/el/1421/jaro2016/UJA304/18_Dieslovo.doc&cd=4&hl=uk&ct=clnk&gl=ua&lr=-lang_ru) **и** і відповідно **е**, шчо [могло](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D1%96%D1%94%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE#%D0%86%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%96%D1%8F) бути впливом займенника *ми*, наприклад: *єсме* <sup>[[л]](//corpora.uni-leipzig.de/en/res?corpusId=ukr_mixed_2014&word=%D1%94%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%B5), [[ґ]](//parasol.vmguest.uni-jena.de/grac_crystal/#concordance?corpname=grac16&tab=advanced&keyword=%D1%94%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%B5&showresults=1)</sup>, *стоїми* <sup>[[л]](//corpora.uni-leipzig.de/en/res?corpusId=ukr_mixed_2014&word=%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%97%D0%BC%D0%B8), [[ґ]](//parasol.vmguest.uni-jena.de/grac_crystal/#concordance?corpname=grac16&tab=advanced&keyword=%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%97%D0%BC%D0%B8&showresults=1)</sup>, котрі, очевидно, можуть потрапяти ся і нинѣ, правда, значно рѣдше, бо хоча би через те, шчо то не стандардні форми.

Дозволю себе не утруднювати детальними вѣдомостями і атласами пошира тих чи гинших форм. Якшчо хто-сь зможить такого зробити — буду не проти. Можна однак зазначити, шчо чинний правопис затвердив дві такі форми.

> <sub>Запитник</sub>
>
> Чи несе така форма якийсь сенс, відмінний від стандартної форми?

Наскільки знаю, нѣ. Особливо якшчо мова про сучасний стандард. Можливо хиба шчо додавати додаткову вѣдомість про самого мовця, однак це в-же не про самого слова.

> <sub>*Запитник*</sub>
>
> Коли її можна вживати?

Зазвичай це пояснюїть ся евфонією, тобто милозвучністю: *-м* [слово з голосної], *-мо* [з приголосної].

Однак, нп., є така думка [Синявського](//uk.wikisource.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0:%D0%9D%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B8_%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%97_%D0%BB%D1%96%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%97_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8.djvu/25) стосовно цього явишча, шчо сформулована так:

> <sub>Норми української літературної мови</sub>
>
> 2. […]; закінчення 1. особи множини дієслів дійсного способу *-мо* може скорочуватись на *-м* (*купим*, *ідем*…, тільки не слід скорочувати тих дієслів, де при скороченні перед *-м* стало б наголошене **и** — *сидимо́*, *летимо́*…);

Проте сучасна українська, хоча би через словники, дозволяїть скорочовати і в таких випадках, бо маїмо нп. ті ж [*сидим*](//goroh.pp.ua/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%B0/%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BC), [*летим*](//goroh.pp.ua/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%B0/%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC).

Comment: Цікаво, що я не знайшов, де б сучасний правопис повноцінно дозволяв/описував цю форму (є ремарки «зрідка _будем_» і «зрідка _-мем_»/«зрідка _пектимем_» про майбутній час, але нічого не сказано про теперішній час; хоча, може, я погано шукав), водночас сучасні словники (хоча б от [УМІФівський](https://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/dictua/)) її наводять (і в майбутньому, і теперішньому часі).

Comment: [«Тренажер з правопису української мови» (webpen) каже](https://webpen.com.ua/pages/Morphology_and_spelling/verb_declination_present_simple_future_tenses.html): «Форми без кінцевого _о_ (_ведем_, _ходим_) допускаються лише в поезії та в розмовному стилі» — але невідомо, звідки вони це беруть (можливо, що це лише їхня власна стильова порада, не обґрунтована аргументами чи надійними джерелами).

Comment: @Sasha << *про майбутній час, але нічого не сказано про теперішній час* >> Це одна і та сама форма, але так, дивненько. Можна також поглянути на наказовий спосіб, де вже шчедро навели приклади, там теж подібна структура: випад **о** і, шчо не дивно, теж з **ъ**. Нічого про розмовний стіл чи поезію. Дешчо очевидно, шчо правопис і більшість џерел подають форму на *-мо* як за основну.